# Android scrollable layout - views not visible on orientation change

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-view, android-scrollview

My XML scrollable layout (work in progress) looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        >
    </ListView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvStatus"
            android:text="0 SMS found"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnExport"
            android:layout_width="88dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Export"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

When load app on testing device in portrait mode, all views are presented and visible:
[portrait mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9SoA.png)
When device orientation is changed to horizontal, only listview part of layout is visible (?!?):
[landscape mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADH26.png)
Does anybody has clue on what possibly is going on here? Thanks.

Comment: do not make scrollview direct of xml. make Linear layout and put scrollview in it

Comment: Tried that, but this causes only one row of the listview is visible on screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the layout you need:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvStatus"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="0 SMS found"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnExport"
            android:layout_width="88dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Export"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

You can also view how will your layout be in landscape mode while constructing it:

[image]

Comment: This was fast and efficient! Thanks a lot man, you are a saver :)

Answer (score 0):

it seems you are missing closing tag of scroll view.

Comment: You are right, I didn't paste it correctly in question, but it is presented in code, so this is (was) not the issue.